# How to encrypt and decrypt text using C?

Tags: c, encryption

I try to write simple application that fetch string and encrypt it.
After I want to get previous string by using decryption algorithm.

AES encryption/decryption will be pretty good

It seems basic but most examples written in other languages but not C. I didn't find any appropriate example to do that. Please help.

Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated. :-)

Comment: Well, what kind of encryption do you want? What level of security?

Comment: The basic algorithm is the same no matter what language you're using. Read the file into a data buffer, call the encryption or decryption function, and write the result out to the new file. You don't need to write the encryption function yourself, it should be available as a library.

Comment: AES encryption/decryption will be pretty good

Comment: @MaximShoustin I have edited the answer to add AES encryption example too. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need the following libraries:

```
   libc.lib
  euser.lib
  libcrypto.lib
```

Also you will need to install openC Plugin from http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/91d89929-fb8c-4d66-bea0-227e42df9053/Open_C_SDK_Plug-In.html

Here is the source code with explanation comments:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <openssl/rc4.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>

//#include<filelogger.h>

void openc_encrypt(int len, unsigned char* in, unsigned char* crypted, unsigned char* password, int passlen)
{
   unsigned char digest[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
   RC4_KEY key;

   MD5(password, passlen, digest);

   RC4_set_key(&key, MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH, digest);
   RC4(&key, len, in, crypted);
}

void openc_decrypt(int len, unsigned char* in, unsigned char* decrypted, unsigned char* password, int passlen)
{
   unsigned char digest[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
   RC4_KEY key;

   MD5(password, passlen, digest);

   RC4_set_key(&key, MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH, digest);
   RC4(&key, len, in, decrypted);
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const TInt KMaxTextLen = 100;

_LIT8(KExampleText, "Encrypt this text!");
_LIT8(KPassWord, "secret");

void doExampleL()
    {    
    TBuf8<KMaxTextLen> buffer(KExampleText);

    HBufC8* password = KPassWord().AllocLC();    
    HBufC8* crypted = HBufC8::NewLC(buffer.Size());

    TPtr8 cryptedPtr = crypted->Des();
    cryptedPtr.SetLength(buffer.Size());

    openc_encrypt(buffer.Size(),
              (unsigned char*)buffer.Ptr(),
              (unsigned char*)cryptedPtr.Ptr(),
              (unsigned char*)password->Ptr(),
              password->Size()); 

  //LOGDES16(buffer); //Encrypt this text!
  //LOGDES8(*crypted) ; //Ór›­Â Û¦  }ÖŠ4 b q 

    HBufC8* decrypted = HBufC8::NewLC(buffer.Size());
    TPtr8 decryptedPtr = decrypted->Des();

    buffer.Copy(cryptedPtr);
    decryptedPtr.SetLength(buffer.Size());

    openc_decrypt(buffer.Size(),         
                (unsigned char*)buffer.Ptr(),
                (unsigned char*)decryptedPtr.Ptr(),
                (unsigned char*)password->Ptr(),
                password->Size());

  //LOGDES16(buffer);       //Ór›­Â Û¦  }ÖŠ4 b q 
  //LOGDES8(*decrypted) ; //Encrypt this text!

    CleanupStack::PopAndDestroy(3);  //decrypted, crypted, password                   
}
```

The text in this example has been encrypted with the pass phrase and after that decrypted with the same pass phrase using the example functions openc_encrypt() and openc_decrypt().

**Edit**

**AES Encryption**

*(credit goes to:abhi)*

For AES encryption Please refer to this example: http://saju.net.in/code/misc/openssl_aes.c.txt

The code is detailed enough with comments and if you still need much explanation about the API itself i suggest check out this book Network Security with OpenSSL by Viega/Messier/Chandra (google it you will easily find a pdf of this..) read chapter 6 which is specific to symmetric ciphers using EVP API.. This helped me a lot actually understanding the reasons behind using various functions and structures of EVP.

and if you want to dive deep into the Openssl crypto library, i suggest download the code from the openssl website (the version installed on your machine) and then look in the implementation of EVP and aeh api implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Start with i.e. [Rot-13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) and work your way up from [there](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rot-13) ;)